# Hindi text copied from YouTube does not save as Unicode characters in Microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word, video, youtube, unicode

I am making some documentation. The title text of a video from youtube I copy paste in Microsoft Word 2019.
Here is a link to the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEgbNz4sV20
the text is बीम में 5 गलतियां, जिससे घर गिर सकता है || 5 Big Mistake in RCC Beam | Beam Steel Checklist  now I paste it in Microsoft word file.
[office non Unicode squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY6Zm.jpg)
so the text copied appears as squares. [] [] [].
How can this appear as text as shown in title videos. The operating system is Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: can't repro on my system

Answer (score 0):

In my test it can display normally.

[image]

Please make sure that Hindi language is installed in your office, if not you need to add it manually.

file - option - language

If this problem still exists, in order to prevent you from accidentally copying to other text containing html elements, please copy the text to Notepad and then paste it into Word.